# Change color of selected edge/line

Tags: materials, 3d-view, vertex-colors

I have an object with complex mesh. Can i go to edit mode and change color of some edges/lines, so they will show that selected color in viewport ?

Answer (score 1):

Blender does not allow vertices or edges to be colored. However, you can color individual faces.

While in edit mode, the material tab of the properties editor has an option to add the currently selected material to the currently selected faces.
[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9323UapgvLk this video helped me to understand better how to do this. ALSO I needed to switch to viewport shading mode first, to see actual colors https://imgur.com/XJKC4SC